Proof of realness of eigenvalue (Using Gershgorin's second theorem)
I am extremely confused by the solution to this linear algebra question concerning the realness of an eigenvalue in a disjoint Gershgorin disk which is centred on the real axis. The below question's solution (also below) seems to me to imply that all matrices with a complex eigenvalue must also have that eigenvalue's conjugate as an eigenvalue. The assumption of complex conjugate eigenvalues seems erroneous to me as I am under the impression that this is only necessarily true when all elements in a matrix are real (or at least the determinant is known to be real).
Question:
State Gershgorin’s second theorem. Therefore prove that if a matrix $M_{n×n}$ has a disjoint Gershgorin Disk, $P$, created from a row with a real diagonal element then the eigenvalue within disk $P$ is real.
Solution:
Suppose $M \in M_{nxn}$, $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $M_{nxn}$ and lies within disc $q$ created from a row which has a real diagonal element.
Let $q$ be disjoint from all other Gershgorin Discs.
If  $λ = x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero real numbers, then another eigenvalue of $M_{nxn}$
is $x − iy$.
Since $x − iy$ is equally distant from the centre of the disc as $x + iy$, it follows that $x − iy$ is in the disc $q$.
However this means that there are two eigenvalues inside the isolated Gershgorin Disc $q$ given that the centre of $q$ is on the real axis.
This contradicts G’s second theorem and therefore the statement must hold.

Double check the definition of $M_{n \times n}$, I guess. Because they are indeed assuming that complex eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs.

A specific counterexample to the version of the claim where complex entries are allowed is $\begin{bmatrix} 10 & i \ 1+i & -10 \end{bmatrix}$. In general the assumption that complex eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs is equivalent to saying the characteristic polynomial is real.

As said by Ian, it must be (implicily) assumed that all the entries of the matrix are real.

The problem statement is strange. On one hand, it is false if the matrix is not real. On the other hand, if the matrix is assumed to be real, there is no need to stress that there is a disc created from a row with a real diagonal element.

Pardon my sloppy phrasing, I should have said that the characteristic polynomial has real coefficients. So this doesn't actually imply all the entries are real, but I think it does imply the entire diagonal is real?

If the characteristic polynomial has real coefficients, non-real roots, whenever exist, must occur in conjugate pairs. Hence no Gerschgorin disc centred on the real line may contain only one non-real root.
